# SharePoint Onlinie - Create Drive using graph service client

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on one project where I've to create a drive (document library) on SharePoint in not exists.

Using following code:

```
                  var newRRRDrive = new Drive
                    {
                        Name = "RRRR-Prod1",                          
                        Description = "Holds RRRR files",
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior","rename"}
                        }
                    };
                    var newDrive = await graphClient
                    .Sites[site.Id]
                    .Drives
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(newRRRDrive);
```

But this is throwing exception that the request is invalid. I don't know what I doing wrong here.. Any suggestions?

Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2021-05-30T20:57:40
request-id: ec6ddddddddddddddd0f72d91c8e
client-request-id: ec6ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
ClientRequestId: ec6dedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Adding image after implementing soln by Michael
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTJsX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new document library, you can perform the same call as mentioned in the [create list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) instead of using the genericList template value. Use the documentLibrary value.

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/lists
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "YourLibraryName",
  "list": {
    "template": "documentLibrary"
  }
}
```

C# code

```
var list = new List
{
    DisplayName = "Books",  
    ListInfo = new ListInfo
    {
        Template = "documentLibrary"
    }
};

await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(list);
```

Comment: Thank You, @Michael. That really helps and I did it create POC2 as library for me. But I would like to see that POC2 to appear on breadcrumb which is not showing up. attaching image for your reference.

Comment: Also, could you please suggest why it is not create a Drive as it and we have to use List to create it as Drive? This will really help to understand how Microsoft Graph API works.

Comment: I see there is a setting "Display this document library on the Quick Launch? " which needs to be set on created document library as list.. Once I set it manually, POC2 start appearing on Sharepoint header breadcrumb ..